# C# Smart If Statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

Is there a way to rewrite these if a statements in a shorter and smarter way?
Please note that checking var for null is important because I want to avoid the exceptions.

C#:

```
if(var ==n ull)
{
    return 0;
}

if(var.ToString() == "A")
{
    return 1;
}
else if(var.ToString() == "B")
{
    return 2;
}
else 
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Editing a question such that it invalidates existing answers is frowned upon; a better idea would be to ask a separate question

Comment: Based on the update - you could just stick all the "letter" values into an array and use the index (+1) as the return value... or use the ASCII character code and a bit of math - it might also be useful for this question to state why you are doing the above (what it's for) as it may give better quality answers.

Comment: Please return this question to its original state and start a new question explaining what exactly you are trying to achieve on the high level.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator and the null conditional operator:

```
return var?.ToString() == "A" ? 1 : 0;
```

The null conditional operator (`?.`) returns `null` if `var` is `null` and `var.ToString()` if `var` is not `null`.

Since `null` is not equal to `"A"`, the ternary operator returns:

- `0` if `var` is `null` or `var.ToString()` is not `"A"` and
- `1` if `var` is not `null` and `var.ToString()` is `"A"`.

---

Just in case you cannot use C#6 (which provides the null conditional operator):

```
return var != null && var.ToString() == "A" ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Does the ternary operator takes care of the null situation ?

Comment: No, but the null conditional operator does.

Comment: @NewUser just as I explained the null conditional operator takes care of that. It returns `null` instead of the result of `ToString()` and `null != "A"`

Comment: @NewUser which C# version are you using?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It is weird I only saw your code the first time and then the explanation appeared after I asked about the null.

Comment: @ Mong Zhu version 6.0

Answer (score 7):

In addition to *Rene Vogt*'s answer, you can use `switch` statement combined with null conditional operator. It makes code more readable:

```
switch (var?.ToString())
{
   case "A":
       return 1;
   case "B":
       return 2;
   default:
       return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, would have written that if the question has originally been like that, but won't update my answer since maybe the question changes then again :)

Comment: Thank you René. I've just added couple of things in addition to your excellent answer.

Comment: I think it's important to note that the **null conditional operator ?.** is not available in C# < 6.

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is a matter of personal preference, but this to me seems like a quite complicated condition and it would be nice to make it cleaner and easier to understand.

First, let's rewrite the conditions to understand them more easily:

```
if (var != null && var.ToString() == "A")
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
```

Now, introduce a method for the condition expression:

```
private bool IsBigLetterAWhenRepresentedAsString(object o) =>
    o != null && o.ToString() == "A";
```

Note that I use C# 6.0 method shorthand syntax. It is nice and short, but you can also use a standard method like so:

```
private bool IsBigLetterAWhenRepresentedAsString(object o)
{
    return o!= null && o.ToString() == "A";
}
```

And then use this method in your original method like following:

```
// ... some code
return IsBigLetterAWhenRepresentedAsString(var) ? 1 : 0;
```

This, to me is much cleaner than `return var != null && var.ToString() == "A" ? 1 : 0;`. It makes the code in the original method shorter and easier to understand.

Also note that `var` is a reserved keyword in C#, so the posted code won't actually compile.

Comment: upvoted, encapsulating the condition in a well-named method is a very good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Possible alternative to the ternary operator solution:

```
if(var != null && var.ToString() == "A") {
    return 1;
}
else {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it would be advisable to check for `null` first, otherwise you might never reach the second condition

Comment: @MongZhu Yeah, just realised.

Comment: I think this is better than the ternary operator + the monad null checking operator. Much more clear to the reader. I wish it followed the standard C# convention and put the opening brace on a new line.

Comment: Wow. Impressive responses. How about if I want to a switch statement for example instead of the if statement. How would the null would be accounted ?